# Difference between embedded and system fonts in flex

Tags: apache-flex, fonts, embed

I need to use multiple fonts in my Flex 4 application, so I compile them into swf and load at runtime. I have single .ttf file for each font. When I dont load font's swf file at runtime, flex uses copy of this font installed on my system, and it works fine - I can switch between regular, bold and italic faces of the font correctly.

However, when I load fonts from swfs, setting their style to bold or italic makes no effect. I tried different ways of compiling swfs (css using mxmlc compiler, fontswf utility, .as files with [embed] tags), but nothing worked. When compiling using css it sometimes throw errors that font face is not supported, and it seems that some fonts are available only in bold-italic style only or bold style only.

I use cff fonts, load them using etcs.ru.utils.FontLoader utility. Fonts are loaded correctly, I check this with Font.enumerate fonts.
So is there any way to embed these .ttf files with all styles available?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://blog.benstucki.net/?p=40) is example how to embed the same font with different font faces.

What about the difference between system and embed fonts, system fonts can differ on different computers of different OS and finally can be absent on a user computer. But embed fonts will display the same way in any configuration.